# JavaScript RegEx - replace first and last occurrence of a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for so as to convert the string `{somestr}` to `:somestr` , but I need to replace only the first and the last occurrences of curly braces, since if there is any occurrence in the middle of a string - it should not be removed.

So far I have tried:

the incoming string `var path = '/claims/{id}'`

```
var pathWithoutBraces = path.replace("\{", ":").replace("\}", "")
```

The output is `/claims/:id` which is what expected, but still it will replace all the further occurences in the whole string

Comment: I've updated the original question

Comment: Roughly speaking I need the string `/claims/{{id}}` to be  `/claims/:{id}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  use the following to replace the first and last `{` and `}`

```js
var s='/claims/{abc{de}}f}';

document.write(s.replace(/{(.*)}/,':$1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should replace only the first and last braces:

`str.replace(/({)(.*)(})/, ':$2');`

Answer (score 0):

How about: **`/({)([}\w]+)(})/`**? See https://regex101.com/r/pW4fU7/2

This will demand and capture an opening and closing curly bracket, and also will capture word characters (and closing curly brackets) in between. Here's a snippet for your example:

```js
var path = '/claims/{id}';
document.write(path.replace(/({)([}\w]+)(})/,':$2'));
```

Note that you might need to add to the character class, depending on your actual environment. Perhaps you should add more examples.

Answer (score 0):

The regex that should do what you need is as follows: `/^[^{]*(?:{(.*)})[^}]*$/`

The test string I used to confirm if this would work is `starting {{ The test string }    here } and here } ends`

The capture group in the middle of that regex (the `(.*)`) then captures the following text from that test string: `{ The test string }    here } and here`